# Odd ping result on network

Tags: ping, tcpip

Can anyone explain why when I ping 192.168.23.019 it gives me a reply from 192.168.23.17?

Then If I ping .23.19 I get a request timed out reply. But I can RDP onto .23.19
These are virtual machines.. Does that make a difference?

Comment: What is OS you're running ping on?

Comment: Windows. Thanks Poige - Never even thought of octal numbering.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As poige hints, 019 is a messed up octal way to say 17. 010 = 8, add 9 to that you get 17.

So when you ping .019, you accidentally ping .17

Comment: @Axle, Actually, it's not just messed but rather totally weird. iputils' (GNU/Linux) `ping` won't even ping such host with error diag: `unknown host 192.168.23.019`. That's why I asked you bout OS you've noticed this on.

Answer (score 2):

`ping 192.168.23.019` is incorrect, I suspect, since 0nn means octal number and 9 isn't octal allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably .23.19 doesn't respond to ping, so it just drops the packets, that would explain the timeout and why you can RDP to it.

Comment: Thanks.
Would this be a firewall stopping it?

Comment: Most probable...